# Python Visual Basic's CDate equivalent

Tags: python, com, vbscript, win32com

I used to have this code in Visual Basic:

```
rpt.ParameterFields.GetItemByName("RowDate").AddCurrentValue CDate("2010-03-19")
```

and I cannot figure out into what I have to convert date to make eatable for COM.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you describe what it should do with the `"2010-03-19"` string?

Comment: Eumiro, It shoould convert date string into COM date representation in the same way like CDate does... BTW found answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, found solution. Bellow is python equivalent:

```
rpt.ParameterFields.GetItemByName("RowDate").AddCurrentValue(datetime.datetime.strptime('2010-03-19', "%Y-%m-%d").date())
```

Approach is the same like in:
[Python date string to date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803852/python-date-string-to-date-object)

Comment: Thanks. I was looking at the same issue having a VBS sample of a COM interaction and migrating it to Python. I will add that I find `dateutil.parser.parse` much nicer for converting text to datetime as it does not stipulate a format string (works by inference and is right most of the time).