# Python date object for MongoDB

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I'm needing to prepare a date for insertion into MongoDB based on user input (string).

Code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
...
self.d_birthdate = time.strptime('6/8/1980', '%m/%d/%Y')
self.d_created = dict.get('d_created', datetime.now())
...
```

The `d_created` attribute works fine, but `b_birthdate` doesn't since I'm on Python 2.4, and I can't use the method discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803852/python-date-string-to-date-object). So, I had to use the code you see above. However, when I try to insert this document into MongoDB, it complains about `d_birthdate`. Is there a way to convert it to a datetime object or maybe some better method? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the `time.time_struct` object to a `datetime.datetime` object:

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import mktime

birthdate = time.strptime('6/8/1980', '%m/%d/%Y')
self.d_birthdate = datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(birthdate))
```

In newer versions of Python (I'm fairly sure you can't in 2.4) you could do:

```
self.d_birthdate = datetime.strptime('6/8/1980', '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: You are right about not being able to use `datetime.strptime` in 2.4. This is exactly what I needed. =)