# Parsing a String date into a date object in Python

Tags: python, date

I am parsing a log file and one element contains the date as a String:

```
Tue Mar 31 20:24:23 BST 2015
```

The date is in `element[i][0]` of a 2DList

What I am a little stumped on (without going about this in some awful compare and replace manner) is how to turn this date into something comparable in Python.

I get a few entries in a log file which are within a few minutes of each other, so I would like to group these as one.

```
Tue Mar 31 20:24:23 BST 2015
Tue Mar 31 20:25:45 BST 2015
Tue Mar 31 20:26:02 BST 2015
```

What options can be suggested?

I am aware that I can input logic to replace `'Mar'` with `3`, remove Day Tue/Wed etc strings, but everything else is somewhat needed.

Would it be acceptable to replace a `:` with `/` I can then split the date into a list by its ' ' delimiter, then compare the 20/26/02 element, but before I go and do all that, is there a built in way? I have searched and found python datetime [1](http://pymotw.com/2/datetime/), which I would use after a lot of replacing values.

Really, I'm looking for a built in method!

Comment: see related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803852/python-date-string-to-date-object?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime).

[Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) are format specifiers.

Something like `datetime.strptime(your_string, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y")` should do the work.