# Python: define a string variable pattern

Tags: python

I'm new to python.

I have a program that reads from `str(sys.argv[1])`:

```
myprogram.py "some date" # I'd like this in YYYYMMDD format. I.e:
myprogram.py 20160806


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if str(sys.argv[1]):
        CTRL = str(sys.argv[1])
        print "some stuff"
        sys.exit()
```

I need "some date" in YYYYMMDD format. How could it be possible? I've googled variable mask, variable pattern and nothing came out.

Thanks for your help and patience.

---

UPDATE:

Fortunately all answers helped me!

As the CTRL variable gaves me *2016-08-17 00:00:00* format, I had to convert it to *20160817*. Here is the code that worked for me:

```
if str(sys.argv[1]):
    CTRL_args = str(sys.argv[1])

    try:
        CTRL = str(datetime.datetime.strptime(CTRL_args, "%Y%m%d")).strip().split(" ")[0].replace("-","").replace(" ","").replace(":","")
        # do some stuff
    except ValueError:
        print('Wrong format!')
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: _'I need "some date" in YYYYMMDD format'_. What is "some date"? It doesn't appear anywhere in your code.

Comment: @Kevin I've edited. It's that clear?

Comment: Again one of my questions downvoted? What's wrong?

Comment: It's a little clearer, but "20160806" is already in YYYYMMDD format. What kind of output are you trying to produce? Should your program say "that input is in YYYYMMDD format, great job"? If the user enters "myprogram.py spamAndEggs", should it say "that's not a YYYYMMDD date, try again"? Or what? I still don't know what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: it should it say "that's not a YYYYMMDD date.

Comment: I think this question was downvoted because it duplicates this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803852/python-date-string-to-date-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you said right, you want to pass an argument in a YYYYMMDD format.

There is nothing stopping you from doing this with your script.

You can run: `python yourscript.py YYYYMMDD` and a string "YYYYMMDD" will be stored in your CTRL variable.

---

UPDATE:

The following routine does the checks you are asking for:

Let me know if you need me to explain any of it!

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        CTRL = str(sys.argv[1])
    except IndexError:
        print "You have not specified a date!"
        sys.exit()

    try:
        parced_CTRL = datetime.strptime(CTRL, "%Y%m%d")
    except ValueError:
        print "Please input date in the YYYYMMDD format!"
        sys.exit()

    print "Date is in the correct format!"
    print "Data = {}".format(parced_CTRL)
```

---

UPDATE:

If you want to parse dates in the YYYY-MM-DD format you need to do this instead:

```
parced_CTRL = datetime.strptime(CTRL, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

I think it is self explanatory... ;)

Comment: that's exactly it does. But the parameter should be in YYYYMMDD format, nothing different that that

Comment: so you want to check if the format is correct? and if it is not, you want and "error message" output?

Comment: If the format is in YYYYMMDD format do other stuff otherwise print the error message. I haven't wrote that in my question to keep it simple.

Comment: Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: It worked! But I had to convert the string *2016-08-17 00:00:00* to *20160817* using `CTRL = str(datetime.datetime.strptime(parced_CTRL, "%Y%m%d")).strip().split(" ")[0].replace("-","").replace(" ","").replace(":","")`

Answer (score 2):

you need function **datetime.strptime** with mask **%Y%m%d**

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if str(sys.argv[1]):
        CTRL = str(sys.argv[1])
        try:
            print datetime.strptime(CTRL, "%Y%m%d")
        except ValueError:
            print 'Wrong format'
        sys.exit()
```

Output:

```
$ python example.py 20160817
2016-08-17 00:00:00
```

Comment: How could I put this on the `if`statement to ensure it's not entered in different format?

Comment: I added validation to original answer