# Python string to date

Tags: python

I'm a Python newbie and don't how to convert a Python 3.5x string

```
'2017-04-19 00:23'
```

into a date and time like

```
April 19, 2017 12:23 am
```

and even get individual units like

```
April
19
2017
12:23 am
```

or get day of week for 4/19/217

```
Wednesday
```

Comment: none in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803852/python-date-string-to-date-object solved my problem. please read my question again.

Comment: What precisely is missing? You have to write the correct format string, but SO isn't here to spoon feed you.

Comment: the accepted answer to this question is what is missing, have a good day sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use python **datetime** module, something like this :

```
from datetime import datetime

date_str = '2017-04-19 00:23'
date_obj = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

# To get a particular part of the date in a particular format such as "Wednesday" for the "Datetime Object"
print(date_obj.strftime('%A'))

print(date_obj.strftime('%c'))
```

This will result in :

```
Wednesday
Wed Apr 19 00:23:00 2017
```

Check out the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html).