# How convert this string to iso 8601 with Python

Tags: python, datetime, iso8601

I have this string

```
14 Mai 2014
```

I want to convert it to **iso 8601**

i read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803852/python-date-string-to-date-object)  and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime),

and first i try to convert string to date and then in i convert it to iso format:

```
test_date = datetime.strptime("14 Mai 2014", '%d %m %Y')
iso_date = test_date.isoformat()
```

i got this **error**:

```
ValueError: time data '14 Mai 2014' does not match format '%d %m %Y'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `%b` token instead of `%m`.
And for use `%b` token you must set a locale.
[Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

```
import datetime
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'fr_FR')
test_date = datetime.datetime.strptime("14 Mai 2014", '%d %b %Y')
iso_date = test_date.isoformat()
```

The result will be `'2014-05-14T00:00:00'`

Answer (score 5):

According to [Python strftime reference](http://strftime.org/) `%m` means day of month and in your case "Mai" seems to be name of month in your current locale and you have to use this `%b` format. So your piece of code should looks like this:

```
test_date = datetime.strptime("14 Mai 2014", '%d %b %Y')
iso_date = test_date.isoformat()
```

And don't forget to set locale.

For English locale it works:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> test_date = datetime.strptime("14 May 2014", '%d %b %Y')
>>> print(test_date.isoformat())
2014-05-14T00:00:00
```

Comment: Also, see https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior for a complete list of things to put in a date format.

Comment: FYI my answer was the first one.

Comment: @dikkini yes, but the other one contains "setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'fr_FR')" and it's the answer exact of my question.

Comment: How do you set locale?