# Convert string '01May2001' to date in python 2.6?

Tags: python, python-2.6, date-conversion

How to convert string '01May2001' to date in python 2.6?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python date string to date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803852/python-date-string-to-date-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code:**

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime("01May2001", "%d%b%Y")
```

Comment: Don't just post code, explain it