# Trying to implement a cache on load of this file

Tags: python, json, algorithm

The cache would have an initial size of 20 elements and upon reaching its limit, to add any new element it would remove the least recently accessed element. On shutdown it should store the cached data back to the file. The data should be stored in the cache according to a caching strategy. Provide options for cache CRUD. Testing Data set : records of student.

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict
import time
import os

if os.path.exists("qwerty.json"):
    record = json.load(open("qwerty.json", "r"), object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
else:
    record = OrderedDict({})

fo = open("foo.txt", "wb")

x = list(record.items())[:20]; x2 = sorted(x, key=lambda k: k[1]['time'], reverse=True)
print(x2)

command = ""
while command != 'exit':
    command = input('Enter a command(options: create,read,save): ')
    if command == "create":
        name = input('Enter name of the Student:')
        p = input('Student ID: ')
        a = input('Class: ')
        n = input('Marks: ')
        time = time.time()

        record[name] = {'Student ID:': p, 'Class:': a, 'Marks': n, 'time': time }

    elif command == 'read':
        z = json.load(open("qwerty.json", "r"), object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
        print(z)

    elif command == 'save':
        json.dump(record, open('qwerty.json', "w"))

fo.close()
```

Comment: ...So what's your question?

Comment: I am currently performing: Create , Read , Save only but on that load of my json file i have to implement a cache (i.e. a another file ) that would contain of 20 elements and upon reaching its limit, to add any new element it would remove the least recently accessed element. I am not getting the part to how to do same in python. Please help...

Comment: Okay, I think I got it.

Comment: Please help if you can...pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually maintain order with a single file, using a combination of `json` and `collections.OrderedDict`.

Your initial setup is like so:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
phone_book = OrderedDict({})
```

When creating, add elements into an ordered dict and then dump it as JSON. The order of keys is preserved. After you declared `phone_book` like above, the rest of the code for `create` remains the same. Note that when you write to the file, you don't close it, so you can't read the contents later. This should be replaced with something like:

```
import os

if os.path.exists("qwerty.json")
    phone_book = json.load(open("qwerty.json", "r"), object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
else:
    phone_book = OrderedDict({})

command = ""
while command != 'exit':
    command = input('Enter a command(options: create,read,save): ')
    if command == "create":
        ...

    elif command == 'read':
        ...

    elif command == 'save':
        json.dump(phone_book, open('qwerty.json', "w"))
```

For reading, you'll have to make some changes:

```
elif command == 'read':
    z = json.load(open("C:\\Users\\qwerty.txt", "r"), object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
    ...
```

This loads the dict in the order the keys were stored. You can now call `list(z.items())[-20:]` to get only the last 20 items. Also, when reading a particular key, you update its "last-read-time" by deleting and recreating it:

```
import copy
key = ...
temp = copy.copy(z[key])
del z[key]
z[key] = temp
```

This will update the position of `key` in the dict. This should be enough for you to implement the rest yourself.

Comment: but through 'OrderedDict'....I am not able to read the Dict. as  I am getting this error:File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\json\__init__.py", line 268, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)


  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: @AyushAsthana You no longer need `z.read()`. That's for reading from a file pointer. Remove that line. You're having the `json` module directly read the file and pass you the data.

Comment: that I have already removed...by mistake i mentioned here...but still I am getting the same error: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:

Comment: @AyushAsthana Update the question with your latest code.

Comment: @AyushAsthana Change `f.write(json.dumps(phone_book))` -> `json.dump(phone_book, f)`

Comment: Now on save: TypeError: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:\\Users\\AYUSH ASTHANA\\Desktop\\qwerty.txt' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'> is not JSON serializable    & on READ : JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: @AyushAsthana It's `json.dump(phone_book, f)`. My bad :)

Comment: @AyushAsthana Your problem is that you keep the file open. The data is not written till the file is actually closed: Look at this (I fixed your code): https://pastebin.com/S6VBBHuE

Comment: Thanks...for pointing it out...actually I'm new to python and I'm stuck on this from hours...can you please help me for transferring the 20 element to another file(cache) updating same by eliminating the least recent used through time-stamp I'm using...

Comment: @AyushAsthana I already gave you an idea of how to do it... now it's your turn. If you are spoonfed, you will never learn. :) If this question helped, please consider marking it accepted. Much appreciated.

Comment: @AyushAsthana Cheers. All the best. Do your best on your own. If you still get stuck, then as a last resort ask a new question and keep it specific. :)

Comment: Just tell me one last thing....I want to sort my list element by timestamp...in the present above code..pls have a look

Comment: sorry ..my bad....I want to print the [:20] elements sorted by time stamp....print ("%s%s" % (k, record[k]));

Comment: `x = list(z.items())[-20:]; x2 = sorted(x, key=lambda k: k[1]['time'], reverse=True)`

Comment: It doesn't sort by timestamp

Comment: @AyushAsthana Just modify the key... It is sorting lexicographically now.

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803852/python-date-string-to-date-object

Comment: Or better still... when you create the record, don't save it in iso format. Save it in Epochs (integer, therefore easy to sort).

Comment: eyah..that is the problem....besides ISO format....it throws error for 'not JSON serializable'

Comment: @AyushAsthana You can do `import time; my_date = time.time()` returning the time as an integer.

Comment: this gives me..{"Student ID:": "123", "Class:": "12", "Marks": "123", "time": 1499076408.3859165}

Comment: @AyushAsthana You can easily convert it to string format later using date time library... google it... :)

Comment: ok...but still I am not able to sort it on above code...and on this data...https://pastebin.com/kzhDL0y5

Comment: @AyushAsthana Just ask a new question. :) This thread is becoming too long.

Comment: You've asked 2 questions recently, some of which have not been received very well by the community. Everyone learns at their own pace, and it’s okay to make some mistakes. However, the reception your questions have received thus far might ultimately block your account from asking questions entirely.

Comment: Oh... Did you try `x2 = sorted(x, key=lambda k: k[1]['time'], reverse=True)` Why isn't it working?

Comment: I have tried..but sorting ain't happening...you can see same in above code...if something is wrong...

Comment: @AyushAsthana `x = list(record.items())[-20:];`

Comment: ok thanks...can you tell me why my dictionary key,value order gets change...every other time I create... for e.g.  "A0003": {"time": 1499078603.4269066, "Class:": "12", "Student ID:": "123", "Marks": "120"},  &    "j133": {"Student ID:": "221", "Class:": "12", "Marks": "462", "time": 1499089539.5566998},               IS IT DUE TO OrderedDict..?

Comment: Dictionaries do not have an implicit ordering for versions of python below 3.6. You can use an OrderedDict for the inner dicts as well, if you wish.

Comment: so if the order is getting changed every time...on every 'create'....k[1]['time'] will be of no use...because it's position gets changed everytime....right..?

Comment: Yeah. Only the positions of the inner dict.

Comment: so...is there any solution for same...by which I can take the 'time' value and then sort it..?