# Convert formatted string to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with a column that has been formatted as "%w-%U-%Y" (Weekday number-Week number-Year)

I'm currently doing the following to convert it to datetime format:

```
for i in df.index:
    df['DWY'][i] = dt.strptime(df['DWY'][i],'%w-%U-%Y')
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: maybe this post will help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803852/python-date-string-to-date-object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['DWY'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DWY'],format='%w-%U-%Y')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `map` function:

```
df['DWY'] = list(map(lambda x: dt.strptime(x,'%w-%U-%Y'), df['DWY']))
```

I personally like the way list comprehension work better:

```
df['DWY'] = [dt.strptime(entry, '%w-%U-%Y') for entry in df['DWY']]
```