# Convert/split YYYYMMDD into data consisting of year, month, day in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

My data looks like this and I need to use only the days. How can I split the int YYYYMMDD into three integers YYYY, MM, DD

```
YYYYMMDD
20170301
20170302
20170303
20170304
20170305
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python date string to date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803852/python-date-string-to-date-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscript strings like so, so just convert your int to a string, and do this, and then convert back using `int()` and `str()`

```
data = str(20170305)

year = int(data[0:4])
month = int(data[4:6])
day = int(data[6:8])

print(year, month, day)
```

Output:

```
2017 3 5
```

If you actually want to convert this into a date object, @Idlehands's answer will help you.

If you just need the day, you can also do:

```
data = 20170305
day = abs(data) % 100
print(day)
```

Output:

```
5
```

Just note that this will not preserve the `DD` format, and you would have to account for that.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** Just noted OP only wanted the day.  If you don't care to interpret the string as a `datetime` object, @chrisz's answer is simpler.

For just the day:

```
my_date= '20170301'
my_day = int(my_date[-2:])
```

The `[-2:]` represents slicing the string, from the second last character to the end, which returns '01', and is then converted to an integer by `int()`.

**Original answer:**

If you want to interpret the date as a `datetime` object for other references, use `strptime` from `datetime` module.

## INPUT:

```
import datetime
my_str = '20170301'
my_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(my_str,'%Y%m%d')
print(my_date)
print(type(my_date))
```

## OUTPUT:

```
2017-03-01 00:00:00
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Now you can interpret the `datetime` object.  You can now grab the year, month, day easily:

```
my_day = b.day
my_month = b.month
my_year = b.year
print(my_year, my_month, my_day)
print(type(my_year), type(my_month), type(my_day))
```

Returns:

```
2017 3 1
<class 'int'> <class 'int'> <class 'int'>
```

Comment: I like this answer, however the question does ask for 3 integers as output.

Comment: thats half the answer, he wanted YYYY , MM , DD as single integers

Comment: `print(b.year, b.month, b.day)`. Although this answer is better than the other one, it's not complete.

Comment: Lately I noticed I fail at basic question comprehension... I'll update the answer.  Cheers for the feedbacks.

Comment: I think we may both have overcomplicated this.  If he really just wants the last 2 digits from a number: `abs(num) % 100`

Comment: @chrisz, even simpler, just `data[-2:]` returns the last 2 characters from the string data.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `for` loop, you could extract year, month, and day, and convert them to integers.

```
data = ['20170301',
        '20170302',
        '20170303',
        '20170304',
        '20170305']

yyyy_mm_dd = []

for date in data:
    year = int(date[:4])
    month = int(date[4:6])
    day = int(date[6:])
    yyyy_mm_dd.append([year, month, day])

print(yyyy_mm_dd)
# [[2017, 3, 1], [2017, 3, 2], [2017, 3, 3], [2017, 3, 4], [2017, 3, 5]]
```

Use a `list comprehension` to extract days from `yyyy_mm_dd`:

```
days = [sub[-1] for sub in yyyy_mm_dd]

print(days)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: For some resson this is not working and is giving me the following error:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: @G.M., I think it is due to the string `YYYYMMDD` that you may have included in the data.