# convert string date to date format

Tags: python

This is a basic question but am getting tangled up

I have a string variable `referencePeriodEndDate` which contains a date with type string

Which I am trying to convert to a date only format

so `'31/3/2017'` to `2017-03-31`

But am getting stuck.  I've so far tried to use:

```
datetimeobject = datetime.strptime(referencePeriodEndDate,'%Y-%m-%d')
datetimeobject = referencePeriodEndDate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Is the date string always going to be in the format d/m/y ?

Comment: Your `strptime` format should be `'%d/%m/%Y'`.

Comment: Thanks, think I'd prefer yyyy-mm-dd please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python date string to date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803852/python-date-string-to-date-object)

Comment: @Stacey the format tells `strptime` how the string comes in. A date has no format - it consists of numbers. Your input is '%d/%m/%Y'. As long as you tell `strptime` it will get "apples"  but give it "bananas" (formatwise missmatched data) only fruitsalat (garbage) will come out.

Comment: `datetime.strptime(...)` = parse a string to a datetime object.  `datetime_object.strftime(...)` = format a datetime as string

Comment: `print(datetime.datetime.strptime("31/3/2017", '%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you can use the **[dateutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil/2.6.1)** module

```
from dateutil import parser
dt =  parser.parse("31/3/2017")
print dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

**Output**:

```
2017-03-31
```

Using **datetime**

```
import datetime
A = datetime.datetime.strptime('31/3/2017','%d/%m/%Y')
print A.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Many thanks everyone, I didn't realize that strptime required an input format