# Date format from MySQL on table displaying incorrectly

Tags: python, html, mysql, date, flask

I currently have a table which is displaying on a HTML page, data which has been inputted into from a form. I think the format for the data in MySQL table saves as yyyy-mm-dd. I would like the date that is displayed on the table to be in the format DD-MM-YYYY.

I have tried looking at previous questions but cannot find a solution for this.

Below is a snippet of my code for the HTML table which pulls information from some of my model tables.

```
<tr>
           <td>
             {{ current_user.first_name }} {{ current_user.last_name }}
       </td>
          <td>
                {% if current_user.tasterday %}
                {{ current_user.tasterday.date }}
                 {% else %}
                      -
                 {% endif %}
          </td>
          <td>
                {% if current_user.course %}
                {{ current_user.course.name }}
                 {% else %}
                      -
                 {% endif %}
          </td>
            <td>
                {% if current_user.tasterday %}
                {{ current_user.tasterday.description }}
                 {% else %}
                      -
                 {% endif %}
          </td>

</tr>
```

Could someone please tell me what I need to add to the date section so that the format is DD-MM-YYY.
Thankyou.

Comment: _I think the format for the data in MySQL table saves as yyyy-mm-dd_ - Find out exactly how your dates are currently formatted then you can figure out how to convert them. If it's a Date object then `strftime()` will work.

Comment: @noslenkwah I've just checked the format in MySQL and yes, it's saved as YYYY-MM-DD. Would I need to convert how it is formatted in the table to be able to change the way it is displayed?

Comment: No need to change your database. Converting from YYYY-MM-DD to DD-MM-YYYY is easy. The most robust way I can think of is first [converting it to a Date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803852/python-date-string-to-date-object) and then formatting with [strftime](https://jingwen-z.github.io/converting-between-datetime-and-string/). strftime can be done inside your jinja2 template or with Flask.

Comment: @noslenkwah I've followed the answer and guide you sent, entering it into my python console, but when i run my program, the date still shows in the YYYY-MM-DD format, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What is `current_user.tasterday.date`? String? Date? DateTime?

Comment: @noslenkwah It's a date. db.Date (and date is a column in the tasterday table)

Comment: Then you can skip the 'Convert to a Date object'. Posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format your `Date` Object using `strftime` in jinja2.

```
{{ current_user.tasterday.date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y') }}
```

If you want to change the format [this](https://strftime.org/) is a good resource.

Answer (score 0):

I think this python script should help. It displays current time in dd/mm/yyyy,you can adapt it for your project. Also consider changing the way the date is stored in the db from your database structure.

import datetime

x = datetime.datetime.now()

print(x.strftime("%x"))