# How to convert string in to date in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string:

```
dat="012915"
```

I want to convert it to a date:

```
01-29-2015
```

I tried:

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
dat="012915"
dat = datetime.strptime(dat, '%m%d%Y').date()
dat
```

but failed:

```
ValueError: time data '01-29-15' does not match format '%m%d%Y'
```

Comment: `%Y` is a 4 digit year. You want `%y`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python date string to date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803852/python-date-string-to-date-object)

Comment: What happened when you tried reading the documentation? In particular, when you tried checking how `%m`, `%d` and `%Y` are described?

Comment: Thank you so much @Loocid,you helped me!!!Thank you every one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%Y` is for full year
`%y` is the short version for year

Your code is totally fine, just change the year directive to lowercase `%y` will do.

```py
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
dat="012915"
dat = datetime.strptime(dat, '%m%d%y').date()
dat
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
dat="012915"
#lower %y
dat = datetime.strptime(dat, '%m%d%y').date()
print(dat)
```

this will give you

```
2015-01-29
```

Answer (score 2):

Trying this out; changing the format string to '%m%d%y' seems to work. Looking at the python docs:

> %y Year without century as a zero-padded decimal number.

> %Y Year with century as a decimal number.

So the first one is what you need. Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
dat="012915"
dat = datetime.strptime(dat, '%m%d%y').date()
print(dat)
```

Change `%Y` to `%y`. If you want to use `%Y`, change dat to `'01292015'`.
`y%` is formatted as `15` while `%Y` is formatted as `2015`.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
date_str = '012915'
date_obj = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%m/%d/%y')

print("The type of the date is now",  type(date_obj))
print("The date is", date_obj)
```

Comment: Please upgrade to python3

Comment: The question was also tagged with [tag:python-3.x]. Also, missing closing `'` in `'%m/%d/%y `.