# Calculate the same month from previous year

Tags: python, date

I have a `date` object like

```
Date = '202011'
```

This is `yyyymm` format.

I want to get the same month but `n` years prior. For example if `n = 2`, then I should get `'201811'`

Is there any function available to achieve this?

Comment: Beside the point, but that's a `str`, not a `date` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module and [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library for this:

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

fmt = '%Y%m'
date_string = '202011'
n = 2

# Parse `date_string` into a date object.
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, fmt).date()
# 2020-11-01

# Subtract `n` years.
new_date = date + relativedelta(years=-n)

# Output in the same format.
print(new_date.strftime(fmt))  # -> 201811
```

Related questions:

- [Python date string to date object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2803852/4518341)
- [How do I calculate the date six months from the current date using the datetime Python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/546321/4518341)

Answer (score 2):

Just parse it into a Python `datetime` object and use its `replace()` method.

```
from datetime import datetime

years_ago = 2
date = datetime.strptime('202011','%Y%m')
date = date.replace(year=date.year-years_ago)

# This is the modified date object
print(date)

# Formatted back in your format
print(date.strftime('%Y%m'))
```

*This solution does not require any external dependency*

Answer (score 1):

Here's a similar solution to the others, but only using the standard library, and as a function.

```
def subtract_years(date_string: str, diff: int) -> str:
    dt = datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y%m")
    new_dt = dt.replace(year=dt.year - diff)
    return new_dt.strftime("%Y%m")

# ❯ subtract_years("202011", 2)
# '201811'
```

Comment: Thanks. Just curious what is the use and meaning of `-> str` part in your code?

Comment: That's for [type hinting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html). So it's declaring that `date_string` is a string, `diff` is an integer, and when you call this function, it returns a string.