# comparing date strings not working as expected

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, date, pyspark

I have a dataframe like below

```
+--+--+-----------+
| a| b|       date|
+--+--+-----------+
| 1| 2| 01/01/2022|
| 2| 3| 01/01/2021|
| 3| 4| 12/20/2021|
+--+--+-----------+
```

I have tried the code below but it keeps showing the 01/01/2022 date even though 30/12/2021 is not greater than 01/01/2022.

```
 df.filter(("30/12/2021" > col("date"))
```

I have tried casting both to dates and it returns 0 records then.

```
df.filter("cast(StartDate as date) >= cast('2017-02-03' as date)")
```

Below is sample code

```
from pyspark.shell import spark
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType

data2 = [(1, 2,"01/01/2022"),
         (1, 3,"01/01/2021"),
         (2, 4,"12/20/2021"), 
         ]

schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("a", IntegerType(), True), \
    StructField("b", IntegerType(), True), \
    StructField("date", StringType(), True), \
    ])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2, schema=schema)


df.filter(("30/12/2021" > col("date"))).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing dates as strings, which will compare alphabetically from the left, so `01/01/2022` is less than `30/12/2021` because `0` is less than `3`.

You need to [convert your string to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2803877/2280890), e.g.:

```
import datetime

s1 = "30/12/2021"
s2 = "01/01/2022"
print(s1 < s2)  # False

d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(s1, "%d/%m/%Y")
d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(s2, "%d/%m/%Y")
print(d1 < d2)  # True
```

To do this in pyspark, it looks like you'll need to set your field to `DateType` and use [`to_date()`](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-to_date-convert-string-to-date-format/).

Answer (score 1):

Your dates are formatted in this order : month, day, year.

Compare dates as text won't work (unless you change the order in the string).

A good solution is to transform dates from string to datetime.

```py
df["date"] = df["date"].map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%m/%d/%Y"))
```

Dataframe types before (result of `df.dtypes`) :

```
a        int64
b        int64
date    object
```

Dataframe types after (result of `df.dtypes`) :

```
a                int64
b                int64
date    datetime64[ns]
```