# fix reference date for calculating recency as last transaction day in data + 1 day ref_day

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

```
ref_day = max(df['InvoiceDate']) + timedelta(days=1)
df['days_to_last_order'] = (ref_day - df['InvoiceDate']).dt.days
df.head()
```

I am trying to run the above code but not working. Getting error as below

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "datetime.timedelta") to str
```

Comment: What's not clear from the error? The column `"InvoiceDate"~ contains strings. Convert them to dates before working on them

Comment: The error isn't exactly much to go with, but I'd guess `df['InvoiceDate']` contains strings, not datetimes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python date string to date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803852/python-date-string-to-date-object)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Your colum `df['InvoiceDate']` contains a string, not a date in `datetime` format. Before running your code, you need to run `pd.to_datetime(df['InvoiceDate'])`.