# Date Parsing problem while Integrating to Oracle PMS

Tags: python, django, date-parsing

I'm recieving date in PMS message something like this `|GA090616|GD090617|`
which means Guest Arrival is at 09-06-16 and Guest Deprature is at 09-06-17

I wanted to parse it as date using python.

I've also visited stack oveflow[[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/466376/16444406), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2803877/16444406) [...](https://www.google.com/search?q=string+to+date+python+site:stackoverflow.com&sxsrf=AJOqlzU7g6szDme_RaGLDjBPuIKgLry_3Q:1675264388758&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwihwa-WzvT8AhVGPewKHRCTB4sQrQIoBHoECEwQBQ&biw=1920&bih=886&dpr=1)] for this but as solution I've found

```py
from datetime import datetime

self.DATE_FROMAT='%d/%m/%y'

arrival_date=datetime.strptime('90616', self.DATE_FROMAT).date()
print(arrival_date)
```

and it's not possible to parse it like this due to its unclear format.
I'm not sure if 09 is a month or a date, but from what I've seen in documents and PDFs, it appears to be a month.

Is there any better solution for this kind of date parsing? or suggestions for my expectations.

```
09-06-16,
09-06-17
```

> Note:
> Please Just take the date from the string `090617` and parse it as a date. That will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with regex matching, you can either split the string with msg.split("|") or not, but that depends on your use case.

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

msg = "GA090616|GD090617|"
DATE_FORMAT='%d%m%y'

ar = re.match("GA(\d{6})", msg)
dp = re.match("GD(\d{6})", msg)

guest_arrival = datetime.strptime(ar.group(1), DATE_FORMAT).date()
guest_departure = datetime.strptime(dp.group(1), DATE_FORMAT).date()
```

Although not fully tested, this should be a boilerplate as to how to retrieve the date from the message. Remember to remove the `\` from the date format, as that is not included in the message.

Comment: ```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/abdullah/Abdullah Iqbal/Projects/python/pythonCommon/DateParsing.py", line 11, in <module>
    guest_departure = datetime.strptime(dp.group(1), DATE_FORMAT).date()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```



Found this Error. Same as I've tried, don't need to parse anything as I've already made a scenario.




Just take the date from string `090617` and Need it to be parsed as date. that'll be help full, and thanks for taking time for me.

Comment: What's wrong with this? DATE_FORMAT='%d%m%y' and guest_arrival = datetime.strptime("090617", DATE_FORMAT).date()

Comment: The above Error happened, it's not working on that particular string even though I'm not able to split it. I just wanted to be on in this format 'dd-MM-YY'